# How to modyfied mapped array of objects properties?

Tags: reactjs

Main problem: I have only access to frontend by an array of object so I have to modified properties (add css and html tags) by modified array.

try to solve:

```
             {children.map((p => {return (
                {
                    ...p,
                    {...p.props,
                    {...p.props.booking,
                        ticket_id: <p style={{fontWeight: 600}}>{ticket_id}</p>
                    }}
                })}
                ))}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want

```
children.map((p) => ({
  ...p,
  props: {
    ...p.props,
    booking: {
      ...p.props.booking,
      ticket_id: <p style={{ fontWeight: 600 }}>{ticket_id}</p>,
    },
  },
}))
```